# Where condition for joined table in Sequelize ORM

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I want to get query like this with sequelize ORM:

```
SELECT "A".*,      
FROM "A" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "B" ON "A"."bId" = "B"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "C" ON "A"."cId" = "C"."id"
WHERE ("B"."userId" = '100'
       OR "C"."userId" = '100')
```

The problem is that sequelise not letting me to reference "B" or "C" table in where clause. Following code

```
A.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: B,
        where: {
            userId: 100
        },
        required: false

    }, {
        model: C,
        where: {
            userId: 100
        },
        required: false
    }]
]
```

gives me

```
SELECT "A".*,      
FROM "A" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "B" ON "A"."bId" = "B"."id" AND "B"."userId" = 100
LEFT OUTER JOIN "C" ON "A"."cId" = "C"."id" AND "C"."userId" = 100
```

which is completely different query, and result of

```
A.findAll({
    where: {
        $or: [
            {'"B"."userId"' : 100},
            {'"C"."userId"' : 100}
        ]
    },
    include: [{
        model: B,
        required: false

    }, {
        model: C,
        required: false
    }]
]
```

is no even a valid query:

```
SELECT "A".*,      
FROM "A" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "B" ON "A"."bId" = "B"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "C" ON "A"."cId" = "C"."id"
WHERE ("A"."B.userId" = '100'
       OR "A"."C.userId" = '100')
```

Is first query even possible with sequelize, or I should just stick to raw queries?

Comment: very useful question!

Comment: Updating (Jan Aagaard Meier)'s answer, add `subQuery=false` option to work with limit and offset

Comment: `subQuery: false` on the top config object fixed it for me. Instead of each join being a subquery and have its own nested where, it ran all the joins, then added the where's to the end. Very cool option. How did you ever find this? I can't find it anywhere in the docs.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Wrap the columns which reference joined tables in `$$`

```
A.findAll({
    where: {
        $or: [
            {'$B.userId$' : 100},
            {'$C.userId$' : 100}
        ]
    },
    include: [{
        model: B,
        required: false

    }, {
        model: C,
        required: false
    }]
});
```

Comment: It all fails if I add another include, that is `{required: true}`. Then sequelize makes subquery with INNER JOIN in it and puts WHERE clause within. Therefore that generates an invalid query.

    SELECT "A".*,      
    FROM (SELECT *
        FROM "A" 
        INNER JOIN "D" ON "A"."dId" = "D"."id"
        WHERE ("A"."B.userId" = '100'
            OR "A"."C.userId" = '100') 
        ) as "A" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "B" ON "A"."bId" = "B"."id"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "C" ON "A"."cId" = "C"."id"

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Is this $$ syntax documented somewhere?

Comment: @xb1itz Any luck solving the problem with a second join? I am running into this as well.

Comment: Documented here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#eager-loading
under "Top level where with eagerly loaded models"

Comment: Works as-is, but breaks if I try to add `limit`.

Comment: @Jan Aagaard Meier i want to use condition where like 
var whereStatement = {};
if (status){
        whereStatement.status = status;
}
if(condition){
whereStatement.'$B.userId$' =  100
}

its not working, any help

Comment: not working for me `missing FROM-clause entry for table ...`

Comment: @BradDecker Here is the the updated documentation link (has been moved) https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html#complex-where-clauses-at-the-top-level

Comment: This comment, just to update link for $$ docs https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/#complex-where-clauses-at-the-top-level

Answer (score 17):

Add the where condition in the include, along with join.

```
    {
       model: C,
       where: {
        id: 1
       }
   }
```

Comment: Make sure to add `required: true` here if you want to use it as an "AND" filter