# Possible to WHERE on nested includes in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sql, orm, sequelize.js

I've got a problem that I've been stuck on, to no avail - seemingly similar in nature to [Where condition for joined table in Sequelize ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262912/where-condition-for-joined-table-in-sequelize-orm), except that I'd like to query on a previous join. Perhaps code will explain my problem. Happy to provide any extra info.

**Models:**

```
A.hasMany(B);
B.belongsTo(A);
B.hasMany(C);
C.belongsTo(B);
```

**This is what I'd like to be able to achieve with Sequelize:**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `A`AS `A`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `B` AS `B` ON `A`.`id` = `B`.`a_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `C` AS `B->C` ON `B`.`id` = `B->C`.`b_id`
    AND (`B`.`b_columnName` = `B->C`.`c_columnName`);
```

**This is how I imagine this working:** *(instead it will create a raw query (2 raw queries, for A-B/C) with `` AND ( `C`.`columnName` = '$B.columnName$')) `` on the join (second arg is a string). Have tried `sequelize.col`, `sequelize.where(sequelize.col...`, etc..)*

```js
A.findOne({
    where: { id: myId },
    include: [{
        model: B,
        include: [{
            model: C,
            where: { $C.c_columnName$: $B.b_columnName$ }
        }]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Op.col`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#operators) query operator to find columns that match other columns in your query. If you are only joining a single table you can pass an object instead of an array to make it more concise.

```js
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

const result = await A.findOne({
  include: {
    model: B,
    include: {
      model: C,
      where: {
        c_columnName: {
          [Op.col]: 'B.b_columnName',
        },
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. Edit: For anyone reading this in the future, note that using `limit` on an include might break this: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9869

Comment: Thanks a lot it took around 5hrs for me to get to this solution :)