# Sequelize - query on model and related model - OR

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i'm pretty new to Sequelize. I have a scenario in which I want to retrieve records from the DB with filters on the desired model records and his related records. I need to find records that answer the query with properties on the "main" model **OR** records that answer the query on the related field.

```
let customers = await db.customers.findAll({
where: {
  location: locationId,
  some_kind_of_string_identifier: someKindOfStringIdentifier

},
include: [
       {
    model: db.users,
    where: db.sequelize.where(
      db.sequelize.fn(
        'concat',
        db.sequelize.col('first_name'),
        ' ',
        db.sequelize.col('last_name'),
      ),
      db.sequelize.Op.like,
      `%${query}%`,
    ),
  },
],
```

});

So in the example above I have a free text search query (query variable), and I want to get all customers with name like query **OR** that has "someKindOfStringIdentifier" which matches query.
Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try the following:

```
customers.findAll({
    where: { 
        $and: [{ location: locationId },
               { $or: [{ some_kind_of_string_identifier: someKindOfStringIdentifier },
                       Sequelize.where(
                          Sequelize.fn('concat', 
                          Sequelize.col('$db.users.first_name$'), ' ', Sequelize.col('$db.users.last_name$')),
                          { like: '%' + query + '%' }
                        )] 
               }]
    },
    include: [{
        model: db.users,
        required: false
    }]
});
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36287978/5430833, [Sequelize: Concat fields in WHERE LIKE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752840/sequelize-concat-fields-in-where-like-clause)

Right now, you are effectively doing the WHERE when doing a join. This is not what you want. You want to JOIN both tables (customers and users) and then apply WHERE with your `or` condition, right?

Above code is untested, but I believe you've got to apply condition in `findAll`, not the `include`.

Comment: I understand your answer but i'm getting ERROR Invalid value { location: 1 }

Comment: Updated a bit, please try it now.