# Sequelize: Where condition with multiple AND, OR combinations on Joined tables

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

My question is in extension to the question asked in the below link with few changes as explained below.

[Where condition for joined table in Sequelize ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262912/where-condition-for-joined-table-in-sequelize-orm)

I want to get a query like this with sequelize ORM:

```
SELECT "A".*,      
FROM "A" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "B" ON "A"."bId" = "B"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "C" ON "A"."cId" = "C"."id"
WHERE ("B"."userId" = '100' OR "C"."userId" = '100')
AND ("B"."orgId" = '101' OR "C"."orgId" = '102') 
AND ("B"."contentId" = 'content1' OR "C"."profileId" = 'profileId1');
```

What I want is to club more set of fields from joined tables into multiple OR conditions. Like in the above example as compared to the question asked in the above link where only the userId  is being added in the where condition, I want to add orgId, contentId etc.

As mentioned in the above link, the answer with the highest votes(74) works fine, but only in the case of a single set of fields like userId. When I want to use multiple fields I am facing an issue.

Based on the answer provided in the above link, I tried below, but unfortunately, it picks only a single OR correctly and the rest are ignored.

```
const whereCondition = {
    [Sequelize.Op.or]: [
        [
            { '$B.userId$': 100 },
            { '$C.userId$': 100 }
        ]
    ],
    [Sequelize.Op.or]: [
        [
            { '$B.orgId$': 101 },
            { '$C.orgId$': 102 }
        ]
    ],
    [Sequelize.Op.or]: [
        [
            { '$B.contentId$': 'content1' },
            { '$C.profileId$': 'profileId1' }
        ]
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `WHERE ("B"."userId" = '100' OR "C"."userId" = '100')` <<-- do you realise that this *basically* reduces your `LEFT JOIN`s into a plain joins?

Answer (score 1):

```
'use strick';


const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const db = require("../models");

describe('db', () => {

    it('A B C', async () => {

        const whereCondition = {
            [Op.and]: [
                {
                    [Op.or]: [
                        { '$B.userId$': 100 },
                        { '$C.userId$': 100 }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    [Op.or]: [
                        { '$B.orgId$': 101 },
                        { '$C.orgId$': 102 }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    [Op.or]: [
                        { '$B.contentId$': 'content1' },
                        { '$C.profileId$': 'profileId1' }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        let A = await db.A.findAll({
            include: ['B', 'C'],
            where: whereCondition
        });
        var aList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(A))
        console.log(aList)
        return
    })
})
```

**Updated:**

- 1. 

```
[Op.or]: [
    [
       {'$B.contentId$' : 'content1'},
       {'$C.profileId$' : 'profileId1'}
    ]
 ]
```

->

```
[Op.or]: [
    { '$B.contentId$': 'content1' },
    { '$C.profileId$': 'profileId1' }
]
```

- 2. 

```
[Op.and]: [ { ... }, { ... }, { ... } ]
```

---

Debug with 'logging'

> Executing (default): SELECT `A`.`id`, `A`.`bId`, `A`.`cId`, `B`.`id` AS `B.id`, `B`.`orgId` AS `B.orgId`, `B`.`contentId` AS `B.contentId`, `C`.`id` AS `C.id`, `C`.`userId` AS `C.userId`, `C`.`profileId` AS `C.profileId`, `C`.`orgId` AS `C.orgId` FROM `A` AS `A` LEFT OUTER JOIN `B` AS `B` ON `A`.`bId` = `B`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `C` AS `C` ON `A`.`cId` = `C`.`id` WHERE ((`B`.`userId` = 100 OR `C`.`userId` = 100) AND (`B`.`orgId` = 101 OR `C`.`orgId` = 102) AND (`B`.`contentId` = 'content1' OR `C`.`profileId` = 'profileId1'));

Comment: Source code : https://github.com/nkhs/node-sequelize/blob/stack-66445426/test/db.js